# ActiveRecord and Postgres row locking

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, transactions

API clients in a busy application are competing for existing resources. They request 1 or 2 at a time, then attempt actions upon those record. I am trying to use transactions to protect state but am having trouble getting a clear picture of row locks, especially where nested transactions (I guess savepoints, since PG doesn't *really* do transactions within transactions?) are concerned.

The process should look like this:

- Request N resources
- Remove those resources from the pool to prevent other users from attempting to claim them
- Perform action with those resources
- Roll back the entire transaction and return resources to pool if an error occurs

(Assume happy path for all examples. Requests always result in products returned.)

One version could look like this:

```
def self.do_it(request_count)
  Product.transaction do
    locked_products = Product.where(state: 'available').lock('FOR UPDATE').limit(request_count).to_a
    Product.where(id: locked_products.map(&:id)).update_all(state: 'locked')
    do_something(locked_products)
  end
end
```

It seems to me that we could have a deadlock on that first line if two users request 2 and only 3 are available. So, to get around it, I'd like to do...

```
def self.do_it(request_count)
  Product.transaction do
    locked_products = []
    request_count.times do
      Product.transaction(requires_new: true) do
        locked_product = Product.where(state: 'available').lock('FOR UPDATE').limit(1).first
        locked_product.update!(state: 'locked')
        locked_products << locked_product
      end
    end
    do_something(locked_products)
  end
end
```

But from what I've managed to find online, that inner transaction's `end` will not release the row locks -- they'll only be released when the outermost transaction ends.

Finally, I considered this:

```
def self.do_it(request_count)
  locked_products = []
  request_count.times do
    Product.transaction do
      locked_product = Product.where(state: 'available').lock('FOR UPDATE').limit(1).first
      locked_product.update!(state: 'locked')
      locked_products << locked_product
    end
  end
  Product.transaction { do_something(locked_products) }
ensure
  evaluate_and_cleanup(locked_products)
end
```

This gives me two completely independent transactions followed by a third that performs the action, but I am forced to do a manual check (or I could rescue) if `do_something` fails, which makes things messier. It also could lead to deadlocks if someone were to call `do_it` from within a transaction, which is very possible.

So my big questions:

- Is my understanding of the release of row locks correct? Will row locks within nested transactions only be released when the outermost transaction is closed?
- Is there a command that will change the lock type without closing the transaction?

My smaller question:

Is there some established or totally obvious pattern here that's jumping out to someone to handle this more sanely?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, it was pretty easy to answer these questions by diving into the PostgreSQL console and playing around with transactions.

To answer the big questions:

**Yes**, my understanding of row locks was correct. Exclusive locks acquired within savepoints are NOT released when the savepoint is released, they are released when the overall transaction is committed.

**No**, there is no command to change the lock type. What kind of sorcery would that be? Once you have an exclusive lock, all queries that would touch that row must wait for you to release the lock before they can proceed.

Other than committing the transaction, rolling back the savepoint or the transaction will also release the exclusive lock.

In the case of my app, I solved my problem by using multiple transactions and keeping track of state very carefully within the app. This presented a great opportunity for refactoring and the final version of the code is simpler, clearer, and easier to maintain, though it came at the expense of being a bit more spread out than the "throw-it-all-in-a-PG-transaction" approach.